# AWS Elastic "GET "API Request using URL --Python 3.8|| Auth AWS Signature

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I am trying to get .json response from an Elastic Search API URL. I have tried to hit it using Postman and it used authentication AWS Signature, Service Name= 'es' with AWS_Token, AWS_ID and AWS_Keys.
How can I connect the same with Python script and the fetch  .json response??

Answer (score 0):

So I am answering my own question as I found the solution, so sharing here.
##CODE PY3.8

```
import requests
from requests_auth_aws_sigv4 import AWSSigV4

ACCESS_KEY=''
SECRET_KEY=''
SESSION_TOKEN=''

aws_auth = AWSSigV4('es',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)

r = requests.request('GET', '##ADD ELASTIC API URL HERE',
    auth=aws_auth)
print(r.json)
```